# Select Sibling of an Event target JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following *simplified* html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item">
      <h1>Item 1</h1>
      <div class="effect"></div>
      <button class="btn">show</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>Item 2</h1>
      <div class="effect"></div>
      <button class="btn">show</div>
    </div>
    <!-- and so on -->
  </div>
</div>
```

all buttons have click event listener. how to select `div.effect` using `event.target`

is there something like

```
document.querySelector(event.target + " + .effect")
```

###### Note

I can't use other method than `event.target` so obvious work arounds like adding some custom call for each button, or adding *id* is not what I'm looking for

Comment: it should probably be `event.target.previousElementSibling`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/previousElementSibling , or if there are various count of elements between the button and the target element, you can do `e.target.parentElement.querySelector('.effect')` (providing `effect` is an unique class within its parent).

Comment: @Teemu this is the one, passing through the parent does the trick in the general way, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `previousElementSibling` property that has a target to get the sibling.

```
var effectDiv = event.target.previousElementSibling;
if (effectDiv.classList.contains('effect')) {
  // do something with effectDiv
}
```

Comment: This does answer this question but what I was looking for is a general querySelector for siblings, example, what if `.effect` was not a direct sibling. Anyway, this does the trick so I'll accept it. thanks